# Dynamically creating new elements for an collection created from database entries

Tags: c#

I currently have an item database with about 500 (and counting) items  in it that's loaded into an array once when the application starts. These items are often accessed (by index) but the array and its contents are never modified during runtime. I'm now needing to create variants of certain items in the database and I'm hoping to do it dynamically during runtime to avoid creating a bunch of item duplicates in the database file itself, as it would more than double the size of it. Since the database will grow in time, I can't simply start assigning the variant ids where the regular item database ids end, as these ids will be saved into user's profiles and they cannot change later.

I've attached a screenshot to make it a little more clearer what the items look like in case it helps. What I'm trying to accomplish in practice is to create X amount of variants of for example the "refined_spear" item for the purpose of cosmetic effects on the items in my game. So for the refined_spear, I'd be creating a duplicate of it, assign it its own id and give it whatever cosmetic effect it should have, and then add it to the items collection.

The way I see it I have a couple of options:

1. Use a list instead of an array. This would mean that it's no longer viable to access items by index. Not sure how big of a performance hit that would bring.
2. Create a larger array than is needed, and give the item variants id's that I know the regular database items will never reach. This would leave the array with a ton of null values, but would allow me to continue accessing items by their id.
3. Simply add the new items in the database file manually

Any input from people wiser than me would be much appreciated!

[image: Clarifying image]

Comment: "Use a list instead of an array. This would mean that it's no longer viable to access items by index" Eeeehm, you can use an index for lists as well. However performance might be an issue if you regularly have to increase the lists size. Anyway this question is unleikely to get a **correct** answer here, as it highly depends on your settings and personal preferences.

Comment: I'd argue just chose any way and see how far it goes.

Comment: Regarding speed, modern computers are really fast. I don't see a possible problem unless you reach millions of items or need to calculate the result of every single item combination/interaction.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain You're right, what I meant was that the item ids would no longer follow a logical order. Currently the item ID = the item's index in the array, but if I was to create these dynamic items, their ID's would no longer follow that order since those incremental ids are reserved to items actually in the file. So I'd probably give these dynamic items a starting id of something high, like 20k, a number I know my items file will never reach.

But that's still the only time collection will be modified, no items will be added or removed from it after the initialization logic.

Comment: Why don't you use some Dictionary<ItemIDType, ItemType> then? If you also need to maintain order of the items, you could use both a List<ItemType> and a dictionary (the list maintaining the items in the order as in the database, the dictionary serving as lookup table). Or perhaps rather consider  System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary (which would basically allow both key and index based access)...

Comment: Shit, using a Dictionary should do the trick. Don't know how that didn't even cross my mind. Thank you!

Comment: You can access a generic list by index, also you can use LINQ to find an appropriate item by their Id